# select from derived table with alias giving incorrect answer

Tags: mysql

There are two tables:

1. customer - customer_id, name
2. payment - customer_id, date, payment

I want to find customer who has made second maximum payments using following query:

```
select name, min(pay) from
(select a.name as 'name', sum(b.payment) as 'pay' 
from customer a join payment b
using(customer_id) group by a.name 
order by sum(b.payment) desc limit 2)as T;
```

Dervied table:

```
name        pay
name1       200
name2       100
```

Actual Result:

```
name2       100
```

Result I am getting:

```
name1      100
```

The outer query is pulling pay amount right but name is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you get is correct for the min pay but you get an ambiguous name.
All you have to do is reorder the 2 rows ascending from the subquery and get only the 1st row:

```
select t.name, t.pay from (
  select a.name as name, sum(b.payment) as pay 
  from customer a inner join payment b 
  on b.customer_id = a.customer_id 
  group by a.name 
  order by sum(b.payment) desc 
  limit 2) t
order by t.pay
limit 1;
```

In your code there are 2 names I guess  for the same column: `payment` and `amount`. 
 I used in the code above the name: `payment`

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked and corrected amount to payment. Thank you so much.